# Parse URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I was wondering if there is a way to parse a URL in JavaScript so that you could get a piece of the URL you need? For example, the two urls below, for the first one, if I wanted to get the number at the end, what could I use? And would it be the same if I used the second URL to store 21 in a variable? Thanks.

http://domain.com/test/?=23

http://domain.com/test/21

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: For the 2nd format: `num=(ua=url.split("/"))[ua.length-1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
```

[URI Parsing with Javascript](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561)

Answer (score 0):

PHPJS gives you a translation of php [parse_url](http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/) function which does what you want:

```
parse_url("http://domain.com/test/?=23");
Object {query: "=23", path: "/test/", host: "domain.com", scheme: "http"}

parse_url("http://domain.com/test/21");
Object {path: "/test/21", host: "domain.com", scheme: "http"}
```